# buttons not working when pressed consecutive times

Tags: javascript

I have the following slide effect that does not work when you press one of the same button more than twice in a row.  Meaning, you select the red button to display its color, press red again to hide that color.  When you press it for the third time, it will not work.  To get the red to work again, you need to select a different color.  This happens with all the buttons.  How do I stop this?
[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k5L5N/)

```
// When the DOM is ready, initialize the scripts.
jQuery(function( $ ){

    // Get a reference to the container.
    var container = $( ".container" );

    // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
    $( "a" ).click(function( event ){
        // Prevent the default event.
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $target = $("#target");

        if ($target.attr("class") === $this.attr("data-color")) {
            container.slideUp(500);
        } else {
            // Hide - slide up.
            container.slideUp(500, function(){
                $target.attr("class", $this.attr("data-color"));
                // Show - slide down.
                container.slideDown(500);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the class attribute once the color slides back down, or else it passes your condition:

```
container.slideUp(500, function() {
     $target.removeAttr("class");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k5L5N/2/